# HTML helpers in Webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, helper

I have a old site that I want to use something like HTML helpers to generate special HTML(in this case complexed buttons). I know how this works in ASP.NET MVC but how can I do it in Webform(not Razor).

I have read suggestions on static methods like this :

```
public class Helpers
{
    public static string Label1(string target, string text)
    {
        return String.Format("<label for= '{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);
    }
}
```

But how is this used in the Webform?

BestRegards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your solution. Add a special folder `ASP.net Folder` called code. Then paste your `Helpers.cs` file at it. Then you can access it.

Answer (score 7):

Put `Helpers.cs` in your `App_Code` folder then you can call it like so from your `aspx` file:

```
<div class="example>
    <%= Helpers.Label1("some", "text") %>
</div>
```