# Building HTML Twitter Bootstrap 3 in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

- .NET 4.51 Webforms

I an writing some user controls and need to generate some HTML for Twitter Bootstrap 3. I was wondering if anyone had come across a class that would assist with this before I roll my own?

There seems to be an abundance of HTML helpers for MVC https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/ but nothing where I can generate HTML from code behind easily. Yes I can use something like [HTML helpers in Webform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173272/html-helpers-in-webform) or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper_methods(v=vs.118).aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder(v=vs.111).aspx but if there is something out there already then I would rather use that than rolling my own.

Has anyone come across anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

If your're talking about `textboxes`, `textareas` and so on, the best way to do it is by making a function that adds your custom `html attributes` to that element.

After that you should do method which returns `MvcHtmlString`

`public static MvcHtmlString CustomTextBox(this HtmlHelper helper.....)
{
    var attributes= customFunctionsToSetAttributes // Dictionary<string,object>
    helper.TextBox(name, value, format, attributes);   // mvc original .TextBox helper
}`

Comment: I was however looking for a solution that was webforms and yes I can achieve this by doing something as you describe and adding the code to App_Code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173272/html-helpers-in-webform?lq=1) however I was hoping there was a library already written so I did not have to roll my own.