# MVCSiteMapProvider with Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, mvcsitemapprovider

I have inherited a hybrid MVC / Webforms project, the MVC portion uses MVCSiteMapProvider to create the menus and the WebForm portion uses a custom built menu creation tool.

I have just created some custom MVCSiteMapProvider nodes and would like to port the whole MVCSiteMapProvider to be used in the webform portion of the project. Is this possible at all? Can anyone suggest any strategies for wedging/hacking it in to the webform code?

thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Although in theory we should have working interoperability with WebForms, to my knowledge it hasn't been tried or even tested. But then, if there were no issues with setting it up, I probably wouldn't have heard about it.

To set it up:

- Add a single XML file that is shared between ASP.NET and MvcSiteMapProvider and configure all of your nodes there. Make sure to use the namespace declaration from the Mvc.sitemap file that is installed by the NuGet package. Note that you can safely add the MvcSiteMapProvider attributes and they will just be treated like custom attributes by XmlSiteMapProvider (and essentially ignored). To make it possible to navigate between WebForms and MVC, you should use the `url` attribute instead of configuring `controller`, `action`, etc.
- Webforms would use the [XmlSiteMapProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.xmlsitemapprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and all of the controls that utilize it to display the Menu and SiteMapPath. Basically, set this up like you would a normal ASP.NET website using the MSDN documentation as a guide.
- MVC would use MvcSiteMapProvider and its HTML helpers to display similar functionality. Note that you can customize the HTML helpers or build your own if that is what you need to meet your requirements.
- For security trimming, you can use the [xmlRolesAttribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming#interoperability-with-aspnet) for WebForms, and the AuthorizeAttribute in MVC.
- For localization, you can pretty much just follow the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178427%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

That is basically all of the functionality that the default ASP.NET sitemap providers have, so you wouldn't have access to visibility providers, dynamic node providers, or some of the other more advanced features of MvcSiteMapProvider when working within WebForms unless you build your own `System.Web.SiteMapProvider` that can handle those details.

Since none of the HTML helpers post back, you might also be able to get away with [just writing the output of the Menu and SiteMapPath HTML helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173272/html-helpers-in-webform) in the WebForm, although I am skeptical this will work because the HTML helpers are templated, which probably means they only work in MVC views. Building your own HTML helpers that output HTML or even output ASP.NET controls is also potentially possible because they are simply extension methods that can be called from WebForms.

Please provide any feedback by opening a [new issue](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/new) @ GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will let you know how it goes. I tried the XMLSiteMapProvider approach which worked apart from I used the MVCSiteMapProvider to use the dynamic nodes and CustomNodeProviders that are not going to work with the XMLSiteMapProvider. I will let you know how it goes

Comment: How do you use the HtmlHelper for .Menu in a web forms page? I want to just capture the HTML outputted from the .Menu HTML Helper and dump it onto the web forms master page so that I can have a unified method for generating the menu (moving away from webforms)

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173272/html-helpers-in-webform). That basically describes the principle. However, I am fairly certain the stock `MvcSiteMapProvider` menu won't work with this approach because it is a *templated* HTML helper, which depends on MVC conventions to work. However, you could [create your own HTML helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) in which you write the HTML on the inside rather than depending on a template.

Comment: Also, have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/363#issuecomment-58678912) - there is a demo of a custom HTML helper (although it is a templated one). You just need to reverse engineer the [Menu](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Web/Html/MenuHelper.cs#L1250) and instead of using a template, cause it to write out the same HTML that [the templates](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/tree/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Web/Html/DisplayTemplates) do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different sitemap files. One web.sitemap with XMLSiteMapProvider for the webforms and another for MVC Portion Mvc.Sitemap with MVCSiteMapProvider. For the webforms specify the url instead of action and controller in the Mvc.SiteMap. I am currently using this in our hybrid project and it works well.